# Wordpress plugin - ajax to delete data - Success state

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am at the beginning to learn Wordpress plugin development with PHP and Ajax.
In the Plugin I want to delete dates from a database. 
Therefor I developed a fancybox, in which the user see information about the id
of the oject and the user have the possibility to delete the object.

The ajax function to delete the object works great, but I don´t get the state "OK" from jason/ajax.
Therefore the function doesn´t show me the message "success" and don´t close the fancybox, if the object has been deleted.

If I refreshed the page the object was deleted.

Want I do wrong and where is my mistake?

Thank you for your feedback.

The Ajax Function to delete Data:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_animal', function()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'tierdaten';

    $wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'id' => $_POST['id'] ) );
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: ' . date('r'));
    echo trim( json_encode(['success' => true]) );
    wp_die();
});
```

Fancybox - if someone clicked the delete button:

```
function showFancyBoxDelete($animal_id) {

// Get the modal
var animal_id    = $animal_id;

var modal = document.getElementById('FancyBoxDelete');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("TestDelete");
//var myBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_delete");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// Button Abbrechen
var abbrechendelete = document.getElementsByClassName("abbrechendelete");


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("InhaltDelete").innerHTML = "<h2>Tierdaten löschen</h2><p>Möchten Sie wirklich den Datensatz mit der ID " + animal_id + " entgültig löschen?</p>";
    document.getElementById("InhaltDeleteButtons").innerHTML = "<div class='btn_left'><input class='button-primary' onclick='closeFancyBox()' class='abbrechendelete' name='abbrechen' value='Abbrechen'></div><div style='padding-right:60%' class='btn_right'><input class='delete' type='button' value='Daten löschen'></div><div class='clear_div'></div>";

}

// auf Abbrechen klicken
abbrechendelete.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

jQuery(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
var id = animal_id;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'delete_animal',
        id: id
    },


    statusCode: {
        '404': function() {
          alert( "page not found" );
        }
      },

    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
            if(data.type == "success") {
                location.href = location.href;
            }
            else {
                alert("Dein Eintrag konnte nicht gelöscht werden. ")
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});             
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the wp_die()

Comment: Look for `wp_send_json_success`